# Pronoun choice for “on”

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, possessif

If I want to say:

> One can do one’s homework in the library

Is this correct?

> On peut faire ses devoirs à la bibliothèque

Answer (score 3):

> ***On*** peut faire **ses** devoirs à la bibliothèque.

is fine and neither formal nor particularly colloquial.

“On” matches “one” here (indefinite pronoun).

> Doing homework in the library is allowed.

This sentence shouldn't be confused with:

> ***On*** peut faire **nos** devoirs à la bibliothèque.

which is standard spoken French for:

> *Nous pouvons faire nos devoirs à la bibliothèque.*

i.e.:

> We can do our homework in the library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

The register is not exactly the same though, the english sentence is pretty formal while the French one is more familiar. It wouldn't fit on a sign for example, it's more common in spoken French.